# How to add multiple redirect based on conditions for multiple domain in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I am using .htaccess file to manage multiple domain direct based on conditions.
for example.
I have a domain that i want to redirect on protocol(http)s://www.domain.com another subdomain that i want to access without https and www like "http://admin.domain.com" and rest domain i want to access with http and www like "http://www.xyz.in,http://www.xyz.abc.cc"

Below are my htaccess file so far, please have a look.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#ssl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ assets/sitemaps/%{HTTP_HOST}\.xml [L]
#www redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(system|application) - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Any help will be great. :)